# Difference between fstab commit and sysctl for writing back dirty data to disk

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, fstab, sysctl

For reducing the number of disk writes, what is the difference between using `fstab` to change the disk commit frequency and using `sysctl` for controlling when dirty data is written back to disk?

Comment: which specific parameters? also it looks like `commit` is ext3 specific

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In fstab you define file system mount option:

> Increasing `commit` value means you might lose as much as the latest N
> seconds of work (where N = commit interval) though most of the time
> this won't happen as software can still call fsync() and get its data
> written to disk, overriding the commit setting.
> [Advantages/disadvantages of increasing "commit" in fstab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155784/advantages-disadvantages-of-increasing-commit-in-fstab)

With sysctl you define kernel parameters (remember to save values use something like /etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf too apply they on boot)

> There are several key parameters to tune the operation of the virtual
> memory subsystem of the Linux kernel and the write out of dirty data
> to disk. See the official Linux kernel documentation for more
> information. For example:
>
> **vm.dirty_ratio = 10**
> Contains, as a percentage of total available
> memory that contains free pages and reclaimable pages, the number of
> pages at which a process which is generating disk writes will itself
> start writing out dirty data.
> **vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5**
> Contains, as a percentage of total available memory that contains free pages > and reclaimable pages, the number of pages at which the background kernel
> flusher threads will start writing out dirty data.
> https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/sysctl